# How to return callback on Collection.Insert in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to insert the bulk data into the collection. Inserting into the collection is happening properly. but i want the return callback from the Oninsert function. Can anybody help me to return the callback.here is my code.

```
var Invitation = require('../models/invitation');
var uniqueinvitations=[ { email: 'tyu@gmail.com', role: 'Developer' },
  { email: 'rty@mailinator.com', role: 'Developer' } ]

Invitation.collection.insert(uniqueinvitations, onInsert);


function onInsert(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error while inserting the data into the Invitation");
    } else {
//i want to return the Callback here, 
        var invitations = _.map(docs, '_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the callback-function ?

Comment: i tried to return the Callbcak in the onInsert but its Not Working.. If you want i can Edit that code

Comment: _we can pass a function as an argument in another function and later execute that passed-in function or even return it to be executed later. This is the essence of using callback functions in JavaScript.[Ref - http://javascriptissexy.com/]_ Now what you are trying to execute later ?

Comment: i now how the callback function works, please can u help how to pass the callback in the  collection.insert.

Comment: Jeevan — `onInsert` is your callback function...

Comment: can you please refer this. link https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.insert/ so that you ll came to now.

Comment: Second argument in `Invitation.collection.insert` is callback function...

Comment: thanks @Rayon for your help. I got it

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work and display id or inserted rows

```
function onInsert(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error while inserting the data into the Invitation");
    } else {
        var invitations = docs.map(x => x.id);
        console.log("inserted : " + invitations);
    }
}
```